# ReactJS with Windows domain login SSO

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, domaincontroller, negotiate

We want to implement ReactJS web app to do windows SSO using windows domain user logged in and then invoke some backend rest APIs to the backend application.

Initially we were using Java Spring MVC Framework with Spring Waffle Library which works with Negotiate protocol and works fine with stateful sessions.

We couldn't see any library where we can do windows SSO and if successful and then only access the application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.